# Evaluate dictionary items by key, value with highest value

Tags: python

My goal is to do the following:
Evaluate the existing dictionary using `[key(string), item(int), format]` and find the item in the dictionary with highest value in key-value pair.

Output the corresponding item (i.e. key value)  with the highest value

For example consider the following code:

```
emails={}
emails={'abc@abc.org':1, 'bcd@bcd.org':2, 'efg@efg.org':3'}
```

The output should be, in the above example, `('efg@efg.org', 3)`

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You can also evaluate by both: ```for k,v in emails.items():``` k being keys and v being values.

Comment: What is your rule to find the max value? How do you say a key, value pair is highest?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I sort a dictionary by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/how-do-i-sort-a-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: _If I evaluate by value, I get the highest value as output. If I evaluate by item, I get the item pair based on the evaluation of the string portion of the key. If I evaluate by key, I get the key output based upon evaluation of the string._ That doesn't tell us anything about how you want to sort the items. I think your question could do with some editing, it's a soup of 'item' and 'key'.

Comment: @AMC I agree. thank you. I tried to make it less of a word soup

Answer (score 1):

If you want the max evaluated by value then you can do

```
>>> max(emails.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])
('efg@efg.org', 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution finds the key with the maximum value; you can then access the dictionary with that key if you want the (key, value) pair.

```py
>>> k = max(emails, key=emails.get)
>>> (k, emails[k])
('efg@efg.org', 3)
```